# Send Angular2 form with pristine data

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms

**Problem: I want to submit a form with pristine data, but the Validators does not allow me to do that, because the form is invalid.**

I'm trying to send a form using data driven approach, with Form Builder, the data that I want to send is inside a modal. The purpose of the modal is that the user can edit some data, the input fields on the modal are filled with the previous data, that is why I don't need to check if the user change the value, however I still need to check if the fields are not empty.

Ignore the selector that is on the bottom of the modal.

[Screenshot of modal][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1GU4.png

Form Builder code

```
this.editProblemForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  'problemDetails': this._formBuilder.group({
    'engDescription': ['', Validators.required],
    'spnDescription': ['', Validators.required]
  })
});
```

Modal code, where values are retrieved, at the bottom of the snippet is a button that is disabled when the form is not valid, **the problem is that when the user opens the modal all the information is already filled, so the button should not be disabled, but it is.**

```html
<!-- Descriptions -->
<div class="row margin-top20">
  <div class="input-group margin-top20">
    <label for="desc_engEdit">Problem description: English</label>
    <textarea id="desc_engEdit" rows="6" formControlName="engDescription" [value]="descriptionEng"
              class="form-control white-space"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row margin-top20 margin-bottom20">
  <div class="input-group margin-top20">
    <label for="desc_spnEdit">Problem description: Spanish</label>
    <textarea id="desc_spnEdit" rows="6" formControlName="spnDescription" [value]="descriptionSpn"
              class="form-control white-space"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<button [disabled]="!editProblemForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes
                  </button>
```

**Solution using @silentsod approach**

```
updateFormValues(){

let formObject : any;
  formObject  = this.editProblemForm.controls['problemDetails'];
  formObject.controls['engDescription'].setValue(this.descriptionEng);
  formObject.controls['spnDescription'].setValue(this.descriptionSpn);
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show how you're setting the values?

Comment: @silentsod I just updated the problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that with Reactive Forms (model driven) you need to call `setValue` to properly update the control value. Otherwise, it will think the form is empty and your required validators are not being met.

Assuming you have control over what you is sent into the modal, then when opening, in your **modal component TypeScript**:

```
onOpen() { //or however you've named it/arguments you have
   this.editProblemForm.controls['problemDetails'].controls['engDescription'].setValue(descriptionEng); //wherever you got that from
   this.editProblemForm.controls['problemDetails'].controls['spnDescription'].setValue(descriptionSpn); //wherever you got that from
}
```

As an aside, you should also not be using `[disabled]` but rather programmatically calling `.disable()` and `.enable()` on the controls. There'll be a warning message in your console log about it.

Comment: It worked!!! I just needed to save first the form object in a variable because TypeScript didn't allowed me to do everything in one line.  Thank you!